# Exception thrown: system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception in system.data.dll

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am handling large data table in sql server with vb.net. I am extracting data from a text file to a datatable in sql server and updating the datatable through multiple sql update query. I am iterating the whole extraction and updating process number of times say 100 times for the requirement of my algorithm. In every iteration new data are extracted from the text file and datatable is updated accordingly. The process works fine for me for limited number of iterations say 20 times. After that I find error written in immediate window of Visual Studio 2015 "Exception thrown: system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception in system.data.dll". But the module did not break or stop, it only hangs for longer period. After that few iteration runs at normal speed. Again after few iterations, same error and same slow speed in execution. And subsequently each iteration becomes too slow that needs some attention and remedy action. I am really stuck up here. Here is my code:

```vb
Public connectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Main Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
Public con As SqlConnection


Private Sub btnOk_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click

Dim i as Integer
con = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
con.Open()

For i = 1 to 100
    SimVehRecord(Main_DataDataSet, Sim_VehRecordTableAdapter)
    'Other function
Next

con.Close()
con.Dispose()

End Sub


Function SimVehRecord(ByVal ds As Main_DataDataSet, ByVal ta As Main_DataDataSetTableAdapters.Sim_VehRecordTableAdapter)

        Dim tblReadCSV As New DataTable()

        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Sim_Time")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Veh_No")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Link_No")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Lane_No")
        tblReadCSV.Columns.Add("Position")

        Dim csvParser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Aus\Result Output\Rom001.fzp")
        csvParser.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        csvParser.SetDelimiters(";")
        csvParser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

        Try
            While Not (csvParser.EndOfData = True)
                tblReadCSV.Rows.Add(csvParser.ReadFields())
            End While
            csvParser.Close()
            csvParser.Dispose()

            Dim cmdText As String = "TRUNCATE TABLE [Sim VehRecord]"
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdText, con)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using

            Using bulkcopy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[Sim VehRecord]"
                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Sim_Time", "Sim Time (sec)")
                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Veh_No", "Veh No")
                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Link_No", "Link No")
                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Lane_No", "Lane No")
                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Position", "Position (m)")
                bulkcopy.BatchSize = 50000
                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(tblReadCSV)
            End Using

            tblReadCSV.Dispose()

            GetDensity()

        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return ds

    End Function

 Private Sub GetDensity()

Try
        Dim cmdText As String = "WITH SimVehRecord AS 
                                (SELECT [Record ID], [Sim Time (sec)], [Position (m)],
                                LAG ([Position (m)]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Veh No] ORDER By [Sim Time (sec)] ASC) as prev_posn,
                                LAG ([Sim Time (sec)]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Veh No] ORDER By [Sim Time (sec)] ASC) as prev_time
                                FROM [Sim VehRecord])
                                
                            UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
                            SET [Speed (km/hr)] = IIF((3.6* ISNULL ((SimVehRecord.[Position (m)] - SimVehRecord.prev_posn)/(SimVehRecord.[Sim Time (sec)] - SimVehRecord.prev_time), 0))>0,(3.6* ISNULL ((SimVehRecord.[Position (m)] - SimVehRecord.prev_posn)/(SimVehRecord.[Sim Time (sec)] - SimVehRecord.prev_time), 0)),0) 
                            FROM [Sim VehRecord]
                            INNER JOIN SimVehRecord
                            ON [Sim VehRecord].[Record ID] = SimVehRecord.[Record ID]"

        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdText, con)
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Dim cmdText1 As String = "UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
                            SET [Veh no of Leader] =
                            (SELECT TOP 1 [Veh No] FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                            WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] 
                            AND 
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)]= [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]
                            AND
                            sv.[Lane No]= [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            ORDER BY sv.[Position (m)] ASC)"

        Using cmd1 = New SqlCommand(cmdText1, con)
            cmd1.CommandTimeout = 3600
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Dim cmdText2 As String = "UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
                            SET [Veh no of Follower] =
                            (SELECT TOP 1 [Veh No] FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                            WHERE sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] 
                            AND 
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)]= [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]
                            AND
                            sv.[Lane No]= [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            ORDER BY sv.[Position (m)] DESC)"

        Using cmd2 = New SqlCommand(cmdText2, con)
            cmd2.CommandTimeout = 3600
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Dim cmdText3 As String = "UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
                            SET [Headway (m)] = 
                            (SELECT MIN(sv.[Position (m)])
                            FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                            WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
                            AND
                            sv.[Lane No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
                            AND
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]) - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]"

        Using cmd3 = New SqlCommand(cmdText3, con)
            cmd3.CommandTimeout = 3600
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Dim cmdText4 As String = "UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
                            SET[Density (veh/km)] =
                            (SELECT CAST(ROUND(1000* COALESCE ((COUNT(DISTINCT [Veh No]))/NULLIF((MAX(sv.[Position (m)]) - MIN (sv.[Position (m)])),0),0),0) as int)
                            FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv
                            WHERE
                            sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)])"

        Using cmd4 = New SqlCommand(cmdText4, con)
            cmd4.CommandTimeout = 3600
            cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

       Catch ex As SqlException
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
       End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: In the Debug menu of VS, click Exceptions. Put a tick next to CLR exceptions in the tool panel window. Now VS will break as soon as an exception occurs, whether it is handled or not. What is throwing an error? Also consider perhaps putting some tracing/timing/perf profiling, or even just `Console.WriteLine("Run cm4 at {0}", DateTime.Now)` calls to see what is really the slow part

Comment: Thanks Caius. It is the problem in connecting Sql server. In some of the Iteration it failed to connect to the sql server. Detail error: "Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=21; handshake=0; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=1; [Post-Login] complete=1006

Comment: Caius.. I have figured out the slow part of my above code. It is GetDensity() procedure.  The procedure contains numerous Sql update. To handle 0.2 million data some times it takes only 10 sec and sometimes 10 min. The procedure runs inside a loop. Should I open and close the connection inside the loop? Here i have opened and closed the connection only once. I am not finding any solution here. Your kind assistance will be highly appreciated.